# isAllowed for a single role (not roles the role inherits)

Tags: php, zend-framework, acl

I'm trying to find out if a role has explicit access to a resource using Zend Acl, but Zend Acl's isAllowed method not only checks the role, but also any roles the specified role inherits, which I don't care about, I only want to know if the role on it's own is allowed.

For some context, I'm building an interface for administrators to change acl rules on a per user basis, so I want them to be able to see if a role is explicitly allowed, has inherited access, or is explicitly denied access to a resource.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you read the settings for the ACL from somewhere, lets say a DB. Thats the place, where you should look at. You need to write it there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at Zend_Acl the wrong way.
The whole system is based on parent/child

If you don't need a parent/child relationship you will have to define each rules for each roles:

Guest can loggin
Guest cannot logout

User can loggin
user can logout

Or you can extend Zend_Acl and create your own isExplicitAllowed() method.